# If / else if / else with query to a database resulting false.

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

I have a select box with an option for All, and then a list of users.

What I'm struggling with is creating something like this.  I have most of it except trying to query the database to for it to check if the variable is in the database.

```
   if ($variable == 'All') { code here }

   else if ($variable != 'ALL' != *[result in database]*) { code here }

   else { code here }
```

I have most of it except trying to query the database to for it to check if the variable is in the database.

Any suggestions how I can encorporate a query of a mySQL database in my if statement.

Thanks

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing your query, but can't you just add a `WHERE` condition if your `$variable != 'All'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if ($variable == 'All') {
 ... do something ...
} else {
   $sql = "SELECT ...";
   $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
   $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
   if ($row['somefield'] == 'whatever') {
       ... do something else ...
   } else {
       ... do something even "elser" ...
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use operators like that.

Replace:

```
else if ($variable != 'ALL' != *[result in database]*) { code here }
```

With:

```
else if ($variable != 'ALL' AND $variable != *[result in database]*) { code here }
```